# Could you explain how error handling works with Express middlewares?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working my way through a book titled "Get Programming with Node.js".

Here is the code I don't quite understand:

https://github.com/JonathanWexler/get-programming-with-nodejs/tree/master/unit_2/lesson_12_capstone/finish/confetti_cuisine

**errorController.js**

```
const httpStatus = require("http-status-codes");

exports.pageNotFoundError = (req, res) => {
  let errorCode = httpStatus.NOT_FOUND;
  res.status(errorCode);
  res.render("error");
};

exports.internalServerError = (error, req, res, next) => {
  let errorCode = httpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
  console.log(`ERROR occurred: ${error.stack}`);
  res.status(errorCode);
  res.send(`${errorCode} | Sorry, our application is taking a nap!`);
};
```

**main.js**

```
const express = require("express"),
  app = express(),
  homeController = require("./controllers/homeController"),
  errorController = require("./controllers/errorController"),
  layouts = require("express-ejs-layouts");

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.set("port", process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.use(
  express.urlencoded({
    extended: false
  })
);
app.use(express.json());
app.use(layouts);
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("index");
});

app.get("/courses", homeController.showCourses);
app.get("/contact", homeController.showSignUp);
app.post("/contact", homeController.postedSignUpForm);

app.use(errorController.pageNotFoundError);
app.use(errorController.internalServerError);

app.listen(app.get("port"), () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://localhost:${app.get("port")}`);
});
```

My question:

How does Express know when to run "pageNotFoundError" or "internalServerError"?

Is it the case, that if there is a request, that is handled by a corresponding route's `render` method, all `render` or `send` methods within middleware's or elsewhere are ignored? This is probably far from correct, but does something like this happen?

Comment: This is already very well explained in the [Express docs](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.error-handling)

Comment: @James Not really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an exception occurs, express will call the `next()` function behind the scenes. Next calls the subsequent middleware function.

When one of your HTTP methods returns successfully, the error middleware functions are never reached.

You can read [here](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html) for more details.

Edit:

So this is a bit tricky. The pageNotFoundError does not actually occur after an exception is thrown. Rather, it is encountered after none of the get/post routes match. So if a request was made to '/nonexistent-path/*', next would be called until pageNotFoundError is hit.

However, if an actual exception is thrown, pageNotFoundError would not be called because it does not accept error as an argument in its method signature. Only internalServerError will be called, because it's the only middleware that accepts error as an argument.

Comment: In which case would the application run "internalServerError" as an example?

Answer (score 0):

in Express js as @Greg said we have `next()`. simply, it's like a switch case that checks routes and give request to that route but if route not founded it give you to `pagenotfound` route and if it's unavailable, it give you `internalserverError` route.

Comment: What is the difference between "not found" and "unavailable"? How does the app understand the difference, so as to correctly run "pageNotFoundError" or "internalServerError"?

Comment: by order of routes, if you place the ```app.use(errorController.internalServerError);``` top of other routes all requested will gives this.

Comment: But isn't it the case, that `app.use(errorController.internalServerError);` never gets executed, because `app.use(errorController.pageNotFoundError);` picks up everything that hasn't been picked up by the preceding routes?

Comment: if ```app.use(errorController.pageNotFoundError);``` has an error, ```app.use(errorController.internalServerError);``` will picks up that.Internal error occuerd when an error exist. @tadadadadi